# Laravel 5 - Artisan::call('migrate',['--path' => $database_path."/migrations/new_migrations"]); not working

Tags: php, laravel-5, laravel-migrations

I am trying to execute migrations from the folder `new_migrations` which is created in database/migration folder

```
$database_path = database_path();
Artisan::call('migrate', ['--path' => $database_path."/migrations/new_migrations"]);
```

On local server its working fine.

My website is hosted on a forge server on which it's not working. Is there any permission issue?

Answer (score 1):

In production, `php artisan migrate` creates a prompt that must be answered. Executing an `Artisan:call()` programmatically does not give you the opportunity to answer that prompt.

You can add the `--force` option to prevent the prompt.

Answer (score 0):

```
 Artisan::call("migrate" ,["--path"=> $database_path."/migrations/new_migrations", '--force' => true]);
```